# How to use stuct from other c source file?

Tags: c, struct

ive got `static struct ARP_entry ARP_table[ARP_TABLE_SIZE];` in `start.c` and I want to pass this table to a `fill()` function in `table.c`

ive got `#include "table.c"` in start.c, cause i need it for that function, right? if i include start.c in table.c it gets into some weird loop or what. Any suggestion?

The point is to declare the table in the start.c, fill it wit the information in table.c, and send it away from start.c

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

start.c

```
#include "table.h" /* fill() */
#include "arpheader" /* struct ARP_entry */

int main(void) {
    static struct ARP_entry ARP_table[ARP_TABLE_SIZE];
    fill(ARP_table, sizeof ARP_table / sizeof *ARP_table);
    return 0;
}
```

table.c

```
#include "table.h" /* self check */
#include "arpheader" /* struct ARP_entry */

int fill(struct ARP_entry *table, size_t n) {
  /* code */
  return 0;
}
```

table.h

```
#ifndef H_TABLE_INCLUDED
#define H_TABLE_INCLUDED

#include <stddef.h> /* size_t */
#include "arpheader" /* struct ARP_entry */
int fill(struct ARP_entry *table, size_t n);

#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

declarations (used by multiple .c files) go to header files(.h). do not include .c files.

include the header file in both .c files.

Answer (score 1):

Never include `.c` files. Move your structure definition to a `.h` file and include it.